# Undefined variable - but included within another include

Tags: php, html

I have `header.php` with the following code:

```
<?php include('config.php');?>

<body>

<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <?php
                echo "<li><a href=\"$root/index.php\">Home</a></li>";
            ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

This is my `index.php`:

```
<?php 
   include('include/head.php');
   include('include/header.php');
?>
    <h1>whattup</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since I included `config.php` in the `header.php` which contains a `$root` variable, I would assume it is also automatically included to the `index.php`. Why isn't this the case? The solution that works is to include the config to `index.php` but I feel like that is redundant if I already included that into the `header.php`

Comment: But you aren't including `index.php`. You just output a hyperlink to it. It doesn't run at the same time as `header.php`. Variables don't persist between PHP requests.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a little more please? The part about "It doesn't run at the same time as header.php. Variables don't persist between PHP requests"

Comment: Now that some more of your code is revealed, it might be something entirely different. But it's less obvious what's happening now. Why don't *you* concretize a bit more of the actual application flow?

Comment: I solved it: `config.php` seems to be a pre-existing file that php conflicts with. So it isn't including `config.php` that I wrote but some other file, giving me an error like this: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Config in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/Config.php on line 44` I renamed `config.php` to `configuration.php` and it solved the problem.

Comment: This question is off-topic because an entirely different issue was the cause.